Set and reset latching (bistable) relay with one coil using four transistors
I have a tiny latching (bistable) relay, an AXICOM IMG43GR (datasheet). It has only one coil, therefore is polarized:

My initial idea was that I just use four transistors (2 x NPN, 2 x PNP) instead of only two NPNs, since I already used two transistors when I used a latching relay with two coils before. So I have drawn this schematic:

Is that the correct way to set and reset the latching relay?

Note that IM43GR has a nominal 5 V coil (3.75 V minimum operating voltage). If you want to operate it from 3.3 V, you'll need the IM41GR.

Oh of course, you're right.

No. You cannot, for example, drive both Q3 and Q8 with the same GPIO14 if you want them both to turn on at the same time. You need to have Q4 and Q8 on the same GPIO, and Q3 and Q9 on the other GPIO.
And note that you will have to deal with shoot-through during transitions, and especially if the GPIO pins are ever allowed to go high-impedance.
A better scheme might be the following. With this, you just need to make sure you never drive both GPIOs high at the same time.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You said in a comment that this is the "first time at all I work with PNP".
This isn't the place to get into a detailed discussion about how transistors work.
For the purposes of this circuit, it suffices to say that a PNP transistor in the configuration shown for Q2 and Q4 "turns on" when the other end of its base resistor is pulled low.
In particular, when GPIO14 is driven high, Q1 turns on and pulls its collector low.
This has two effects:

The current drawn through R4 turns on Q4.
Q1 and Q4 together allow current to flow right-to-left through the relay coil.

When GPIO14 is driven low again, this shuts off Q1.
But the current through the coil still wants to go somewhere, and one place it can go is the collector of Q2.
From there, it flows to the base and through R2, where its energy is disspated.
The simulation by @devnull gives an illustration of this, but some of the details are wrong.

This is the correct answer; for some reason I read your schematic as having opposing transistors on opposing GPIOs.

Thanks! About reverse voltage, what should I place here? I believe using 2 x 1N4148 would not be possible, since they would simply cause a short.

@Tintenfisch The fly back diodes should be a pair of 5V6 Zeners, back-to-back in series (ie either cathodes or anodes connected together). This series combination is then connected across the coil.

In practice, it shouldn't be a problem. Flyback currents will flow through the B-C junctions of Q2 and Q4 and their associated base resistors.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks! You say across the coil, do mean one diode at each +/- (set) and +/- (reset) of the coil or parallel to the coil such as a normal flyback diode?

It works fine without diodes from all 390 to 560,  https://tinyurl.com/28l4mp4o

@DaveTweed First, thanks a lot for the answer with the schematic, which seems to be smart. But unfortunately I don't understand it (first time at all I work with PNP), do you mind adding an explanation to it how it works and if applicable diodes to protect against reverse voltage?

@DaveTweed Just noticed you updated your answer and added a great explanation, now I get it! The schematic is in fact really smart. And due to the resistors no flyback diodes are required. However, just out of the interest, if I would add two 5V6 Zeners back-to-back in series, are they added in parallel to the coil?

Yes, as @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica described above.


explanation to it how it works and if applicable diodes to protect against reverse voltage?

Dave's answer rely on the fact that the BJT PN junctions, which form the collectors and bases of the transistors connected to +Vcc, conduct to consume the current when the transistors turn off.
Q4 turns off then Q3 Collector-Base junction is momentarily directly polarized and start conducting until the inductor current is zeroed:

Q3 turns off then Q4 Collector-Base junction is momentarily directly polarized and start conducting until the inductor current is zeroed:


What you are trying to build with your transistors is called an
H-bridge. You could, instead, buy an H-bridge IC that integrates
everything in one package. Classic references are the L293D (dual) and
the L9110H (single). They both come with built-in flyback diodes.
